# Start application with its window hidden

Tags: javascript, node-webkit, nwjs

I have a NWJS app that should run in system tray and only show main window if user requests it. So far I have this code to make it happen:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "helloworld",
  "bg-script": "bg.js",
  "main": "index.html"
}
```

in my index.html:

```
var win = nw.Window.get();
win.hide();
```

bg.js:

```
var tray = new nw.Tray({ icon: 'icon.png' });
var gui = require('nw.gui');
var menu = new nw.Menu();
menu.append(new nw.MenuItem({ 
    label: 'Quit', 
    click() {
        gui.App.closeAllWindows();
    } 
}));
tray.menu = menu;
```

The only issue is that a window flashes momentarily before disappearing. Is it possible to ensure it starts in hidden state instead of hiding it manually as I am doing?

Comment: Can you please add a JSFiddle for that?

Comment: it's a nwjs standalone app, i can't create a jsfiddle for it

Comment: @andrei May i ask why you are using `nwjs` instead of `electron`?

Comment: no particular reason. is one better than the other?

Comment: @andrei To my knowledge, `electron` is more commonly used. And to be fair, this was the first time I heard about `nwjs` so i might just be bias.

Comment: i think it went under `node-webkit` before. although I might end up switching to electron, i've never used either one until now.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer. Had to add to my package.json:

```
  "window": {
    "show": false
  }
```

Comment: Very good to know. Only downside is that this still uses the GPU etc as though the window was visible.